# Not able to scroll the page after moving the pdf controls to the bottom of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf.js, asp.net-core-6.0

I got a scenario where I need to move the pdf controls (rotate, zoom-in/zoom-out....) to the bottom of the page. But, when did that I was not able to scroll the page since the scroll bar is fixed. Is there any solution/ work around?

I tried changing css but didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.